# Adding numbers from a file - Python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to add numbers by reading a file.

The file has texts and numbers, so I need only numbers and add them to display the total.

It is always showing the value as zero. Don't know where I do wrong.

Here's the code:

```
import re
file1 = open('Actual.txt')
line = file.read().rstrip()
numlist = list()
for line in file1:
    list = re.findall(r'[0-9.]+',line)
    if len(list)>0:
        num = int(list)
        numlist.append(num)
total = 0
for sum in numlist:
    total += sum
print (total)
```

Comment: don't give keyword names for variables.

Comment: `num = int(list)` the variable `list` is supposed to be a python list, you may not wan't to convert that list into integer

Comment: Further, the for-loop: `for sum in numlist` is not necessary, you can do `sum(numlist)`. Also, the line: `line = file.read().rstrip()` is not used...

Comment: The script you've shown blows up well before outputing anything. It helps to make sure your script demonstrates your problem before posting.

Comment: Can you provide your input file??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you:

```
import re
file1 = open('so.txt')

numlist = list()
for line in file1:
    line_list = re.findall(r'[0-9.]+',line)
    if len(line_list) > 0:
        numlist.extend(line_list)

print numlist
total = 0
for sum in numlist:
    total += int(sum)
print (total)
```

Comment: It gives a zero and blank list

Comment: Its working for me Arun...can you show me the content of your file you are reading.

Comment: Sample text from the file - to your partner (the computer), leaving more time 
8673 for you to do the 2261
things that you are uniquely suited for.  You bring 
1041 creativity, intuition, and inventiveness to this 8588
partnership.

Comment: I have to extract the numbers and add it.

Comment: ok got it ...just remove the '.' from your regular expression pattern and then try. Its actually matching for '.' too ...

Comment: Nope, still same result. Its not adding for some reason.

Comment: Ok, sorry you are right. I removed '.' and it listed all the numbers. But not summing or adding it.

Comment: ok in your system you are able to get the contents from your file....i mean if you print each line you can see the contents.

Comment: Sorry again i see the added number also. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of errors- I used `ast.literal_eval` to convert `strings` into `int` (`int` function i.e.`int(list)`)Try something like-

```
import re,ast
file1 = open(r"C:\Actual.txt")
numlist = list()
for line in file1:
    lst = re.findall(r'[0-9.]+',line)
    if len(lst)>0:
        num = [ast.literal_eval(i.strip()) for i in lst]# or use [int(i.strip()) for i in lst]
        numlist=numlist+num
total = 0
for sum in numlist:
    total += sum
print (total)
```

Comment: Output is still zero!

Comment: Um, line 3 raises an exception. and what are we doing the `literal_eval` for? We already know its a string of digits.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with lists of things you can frequently do all of the work in one fell swoop. `re.findall` will find everything in the file and `sum` will sum them all up after converting to `int`. So, with a bit of debug code to generate a test file, you can:

```
import re

# todo: debug - generate a test file
open('Actual.txt', 'w').write("""ddenww123 4enale 56asdfr
7 lakjer 8910 222

""")

with open('Actual.txt') as fp:
    total = sum(int(val) for val in re.findall(r'\d+', fp.read()))    
print(total)
```